# Позиционирование элемента в ячейке таблицы

Tags: html, css

День добрый. Столкнулся с проблемой, которая ввела в ступор, и без понятия как разрешить.
Суть проблемы заключается в том, если название предмета, которое в свою очередь, указано в ячейке таблицы слишком длинное, например будет занимать две или три строчки, то блок *item-price* и кнопки *btn-buy* с *btn-gift* сместятся вниз на N дополнительных строчек с наименовании предмета. А если, например, будет 4 строчки, то блоки и вовсе скроются. Пример 4 строчек - https://jsfiddle.net/Iwai_/uw2b4f87/3/
Меня интересует как задать блокам позиционирование, чтобы они не отталкивались от `height` блока с текстом, или же наоборот самому блоку с названием, дабы не влиял на нижние блоки.
`absolute` просто "вываливает" блоки из ячейки таблицы, что не вариант.
Заранее спасибо, если поясните, ибо уже самому интересно.

```css
table.items-36>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #323232;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.td-item {
  background: crimson;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.item-title {
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 102%;
  background: #00000080;
  padding: 2px 0 5px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all linear .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear .3s;
}

.td-item:hover .item-title {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.td-item:hover .btn-buy {
  transform: translateX(29px);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.td-item:hover .btn-gift {
  transform: translateX(29px);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.btn-buy {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
  bottom: -63px;
  border: none;
  background: #93C31F;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.btn-buy:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #638c00;
}

.btn-gift {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
  bottom: -62px;
  border: none;
  background: orange;
  outline: 0;
  width: 28px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.btn-gift:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #c17d00;
}

.item-price {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -26px;
  right: -84px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px dotted;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  background: #ffa500;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="items-36">
  <tr>
    <td class="td-item">
      <div class="item-title">Предмет 1</div><button type="" class="btn-buy" role="button"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button><br><button type="" class="btn-gift" role="button"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i></button>
      <div class="item-price">123 ₽</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 21- век на дворе, когда вы про эти таблицы забудете....

Comment: @Air, согласен:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде я к сожалению не разобрался но есть вариант на более новой технологии - flexbox

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat");
.product {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2423f;
  background-image:url(https://static.admagazine.ru/resize_cache_imm/iblock/e12/ff92/610x430_Quality97_650x459_Quality97_03.jpg);
  background-size:110%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition:0.4s background-size;
  background-position:center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.product:hover
{
  background-size:120%;
}
.product .action {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.product .action .actions {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 2px;
  transition: 0.7s visibility, 0.7s opacity;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.product .action .price {
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  background: #ffdd00;
}

.product:hover .prodtitle {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.product:hover .action .actions {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.product .prodtitle {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s opacity, 0.4s visibility;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="product">
  <div class="prodtitle">Название <br> Очень <br>Большое</div>
  <div class="action">
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="buy"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
      <span class="gift">
        <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
      123р
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```